# Top right x button doesn't completely close the program

Tags: c#, winforms

So, my project currently has two forms (Form1, Form2). When a user presses the login button Form1 is hidden and Form2 is shown. For some reason while running the program, if you press the X at the top right of Form2 it will close Form2 but keep Form1 running and hidden. How do I set it so that the X button will close both forms completely (so that you don't need to go back into Visual Studio to close it).

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `Form1` is the 'main' form, in other words, that's the form that's launched when you launch the application. So this would be your main thread, and `Form2` is a form that's opened upon some event, and that form runs in a different thread.

So, when the `Form2` is closed if you want the main program to exit as well (although this doesn't quite seem like a great design idea), then you'd have to use `Application.Exit()`.

You can capture your form 'closing' event in your `Form2` by adding the `Form2_FormClosing` event handler, and in it, you call the above method.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work - when closing Form2 Form1 still remained open.